# Django: form.is_valid() false django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to save user's input to database. But i am getting error like:

```
form.is_valid() = False.
```

Do you  guys have any idea, why this code generate `is_valid() == False` ?

### models.py

```
class PortDateInit(models.Model): 

     start_date = models.DateField()
     end_date = models.DateField()

     def __str__(self):
     return f"from {self.start_date} to {self.end_date} "
```

### forms.py

```
class DateFrom(forms.ModelForm):

      start_date = forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={"type": "date"}))
      end_date = forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={"type": "date"}))

      class Meta:
          model = models.PortDateInit
          fields = "__all__"
```

### views.py

```
form_date = forms.DateFrom()

if request.method == "POST":
    form_date = forms.DateFrom(request.POST)
    print(form_date.is_valid())
    if form_date.is_valid():
        form_date.save()
        
context = {
    #"ticker_info": list_only_ticker,
    "form": form_date,

}

return render(request, "makeports/first1.html", context)
```

### first1.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action ="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}} 
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using NumberInput widget?
Actually, why you need a widget in this case?
I think if you just added the fields to the form meta fields or even use DateInput widget, it should work fine

Comment: Thank you Ashraf ! DateInput Widget fixed the problem !!